# regex pattern/text analysis

Tags: python, regex, nlp

**edit: I’ve looked more into it and I’ll present it easier for both you guys and for me:

specific str, a bunch of stuff that I can’t know

the str inside the square brackets is what I need to find.

So how do I present the *bunch of stuff inside*?

I tried `.*` and `.*?` And both did not work..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, `specific string here.*\n.*\[(.*?)]`?

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'specific string.*\n\[(.*?)\]', 'specific string hello\n[test]'))
```

This outputs:

```
['test']
```